# Why don't I have to import Foundation before using NSBundle in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, avfoundation

In my code below, I am using NSBundle. According to the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/bundleWithURL:), you need to import Foundation to use NSBundle.

However, in my code below, I don't import Foundation but I am able to use NSBundle. Why is this?

I thought it might be because I import AVFoundation and AVFoundation inherits from NSObject; however, when I read the documentation, AVFoundation isn't listed as being inherited from NSObject.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie_quote", ofType: "mp3") {
        var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)

    }else {
        println("the file path is empty")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func playSlowAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe I originally misunderstood the documentation for AVFoundation. I figured this out thanks to Dan's post. According to the AVFoundation documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html#other), NSObject is a class inherited from AVFoundation (in addition to being inherited by UIKit as Dan mentioned). In my original post, I was looking at NSObject documentation, but not looking to see what frameworks included NSObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIKit` imports `Foundation` and you inherit anything the things you import publicly import.

Comment: Does AVFoundation also import Foundation? Is there a good way to find out what modules are imported by other modules?